# Pointing sbt configuration to private repository

Tags: scala, sbt

I have downloaded sbt and am trying to run `sbt eclipse` to create a Scala eclipse project.

This error is thrown:

```
:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.type
safe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
```

It appears to be a problem accessing the default repository within our organization.

In order to point to an internal maven repository, what has to be done, for instance, is there anyway of adding this to the `sbtconfig` file? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Tried adding this in the sbtconfig file:

```
-Dsbt.repository.config="http://abcdnexus999.company.com:8080/nexus/content/main/"
```

but its not the right solution.

The solutions I see all refer to defining a local repository within the `build.sbt` file - but that only exists within a project, which I don't have yet and want to create.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a `~/.sbt/repositories` file?

You can find more information [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html).

Comment: where does this file live? I saw the link but the file location and name are not clear, thanks

Comment: You will have to create it. You will see your ".sbt" folder inside your home folder. You should create the "repositories" file there.

Comment: It doesn't need any extension.

Comment: Created the file with the following content:[repositories]
local 
my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://e00000000002.company.com:8080/nexus/content//main/
my-maven-proxy-releases: http://e00000000002.company.com:8080/nexus/content//main/
The documentation also states that the following has to be placed in a 'launcher' script:
-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
Its not clear what the 'launcher script' refers to

Comment: It looks like you are about to start using your repositories.
The launcher script, as I understand it, is sbt with the `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` option.

Comment: Within sbt file, at end of 'noshare_opts' definition, added -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true, but local maven repository does not appear to be being picked up